# Compiz changes won't save and Launcher missing

Tags: unity, launcher, compiz, unity-dash, ccsm

I have a problem very similar to this:
[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)
But I've tried many options and nothing seems to be working. One thing notable is that any changes I make with the Compiz Manager don't save. I install ccsm, run it, go to the Unity plugin, see it's not checked, check it, and close. When I go back to the home menu of ccsm, not closing it, and go back, its still checked. But when I reboot or even just exit ccsm and go back, Unity plugin is disabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: What "many options" have you tried?

Comment: All the options in the linked question and a few other small things from others. I know I did this:

sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

setsid unity

Comment: Ohhh... Those are two commands, not one, and meant to be run as the user, not with sudo. I suggest reinstalling the OS. Otherwsie, if you want help troubleshooting As Ubuntu is not the place because it has a Q&A format. It isn't designed for back and forth troubleshooting.

Comment: Right, I did them separately. It just didn't create a new line like I suspected.